# SQL: How can I add to a table without some duplicates?

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, duplicates

So I am currently trying to take one table and add it into another table but for some reason it is not working the way I want it to.
There are three columns in both the tables and I only want to add each row of data from table 2 to table 1 if the first 2 columns of table 2 are not already in table 1 (I dont care about the 3rd column)

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 
    FROM table2 as a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.col1, b.col2 
                      FROM table1 as b
                      WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2);
```

I checked around and this seems that it should work but it isn't but can anyone see why?

Comment: This syntax is correct -- it's sometimes called an anti-join.  This is actually the preferred way to do what you are attempting.  The only thing I would add is that the columns in the "not exists" within the select are unnecessary.  With a semi or anti-join, you can "select 1" or "select null" for simplicity.  That said, there is nothing wrong with what you did.  Can you explain the error and show some sample before/after data for both tables.  *What you did should work*

Comment: @spaceboound This query is proper. You might be going wrong somewhere else.It would be better if you can put the screenshot the error message or output you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I often have trouble when there are two fields to search for. One way is to combine them together:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
     SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 from table2 as a
     WHERE concat(a.col1,':', a.col2) 
     NOT IN (SELECT concat(col1,':',col2) from table1);
```

Another way is a left join:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
     SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 
     from table2 as a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 as b
     ON a.col1 = b.col1
     AND a.col2 = b.col2
     WHERE b.col1 IS NULL AND b.col2 IS NULL;
```

For example 2, it is better to use a primary key in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
(SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 
FROM table2 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.col1, b.col2 
                  FROM table1 b
                  WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2));
```

I guess for table name as is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
merge into tab2 a
using
(select col1,col2,col3 from tabl1) b
on
(b.col1=a.col1 and b.col2=a.col2)
when not matched then
insert (a.col1,a.col2,a.col3)
values
(b.col1,b.col2,b.col3);
```